# Unity3d share screenshot and link error on android 6 up to

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please tell me how to share screenshot and link in Unity? I used some way and error when test on android 6 up to. thanks so much!

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: still works on samsung s5 (android4.4) but on S8 when push button sharing does not work and also disabled button. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In spite of poorly asked question, my skill of psychic tells me that your problem is caused by changes in Android security paradigm. In order to support new versions of Android system you have to adapt your sharing method to use `FileProvider`.

You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) or google more info youself. Hope it will point you to right direction.